# Error with EnterpriseLibrary 5.0.414.0 after opening the project with VS2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, enterprise-library

I have a website written in VS2010 that uses a web reference to a service that uses EnterpriseLibrary 5.0.414.0.

When i worked with VS2010 everything was ok, but once i opened it with VS2012 RTM i started getting the following error (i get the same error when i open the project in VS2010 too)

```
Reference.svcmap: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=5.0.414.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. 
The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Please advice.

Comment: possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849377/problem-when-trying-to-configure-enterprise-library-5-0-data-access-application ?

Comment: Where does the assembly live in your project?  And how are you referencing it?

Answer (score -1):

This can happen if you are missing the other enterprise library blocks needed by the mentioned assembly (and copy local true as well), which are:

```
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll
Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.dll
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Interception.Configuration.dll
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Interception.dll
```